# How to determine if a person is on the line or distance from it

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

There is a base table with the following structure:

```
id - AUTO_INCREMENT
name_hotel - varchar
coordinates - multilinestring
```

The coordinates form a line [image]

In the database, it is written like this:

> 'MULTILINESTRING((37.7721763 55.7042836,37.7728844 55.704205))',0

And there are the coordinates of the person: `37.77247, 55.7042`

I need to find out if a person is on this line or what is his distance from this line in meters.

I do not understand how to do this in the case of **multilinestring**

My version MySQL 5.5.68

Comment: They could be in the shop across the street, and the poor quality GPS in phones would report they are in a position in line.

Comment: @Vince it's not scary. the main thing to determine is on the line or distance from the line in meters

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily do that in 5.5. In 5.6 there is the OGC ST_Distance function which makes this query trivial.

Comment: @thewild I assume you mean such a request ?: SELECT 
ST_Distance(
 `coordinates`,
 Point(37.77247, 55.7042)
 )
from `parking`
as Distance2

Comment: @iKey Yes, precisely. This should return 0 if "Point" is on the MultiLinestring, and its disance from the MultiLineString otherwise. Note the the distance should be returned in projected coordinates, and since your coordinates are in 4326 you will get degrees and not meters. You should reproject your data before computing the distance to get meters.